# Can you use Python mysql.connector on actual Server?

Tags: python, mysql

I have been using the mysql.connector module with Python 2.7 and testing locally using XAMPP.  Whenever I upload my script to the server, I am getting an import error for the mysql.connector module.  I am assuming this is because, unlike my local machine, I have not installed the mysql.connector module on the server.

My question is: can I somehow use the mysql.connector module on the server or is this something only for local development?  I have looked into it, and apparently do not have SSH access for my server, only for the database.  As well, if I cannot use the mysql.connector module, how do I connect to my MySQL database from my Python script on the server?

Comment: Did you install the dependency on the server itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can use the mysql.connector on the server, and it can be done without SSH or any special access!

Download it from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/2.1.html
(Click on the "Development Releases" tab and download the zip archive)

After you unzip, take the entire "mysql" folder from the lib directory and upload it to the server (wherever your other Python files are, e.g. cgi-bin or similar).

Change the entire mysql directory permission to 755 recursively.

Now you can use it in any Python script on the server by using "import mysql.connector as conn" (or name it whatever you want to)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql.connector on the server. However, you will have to install it first. Do you have root (admin) access? If no, you might need help from the server admin.